# How to say "the third time since I started making..."

Tags: grammar

I want to say:

> Now may be the third or fourth time since I started making this cuisine.

And my attempt is as follows:

> 今はこの料理を作るのを始めて、三、四回目かもしれない。

## Bonus examples

More examples might help me understand the grammar in question.

- It is the 3rd time since I started visiting your house.
- Tomorrow will be my 3rd visit since I started visiting this museum 5 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give this one a shot.

```
この料理を作ってもう３・４回目になるだろうな。
```

I think the main thing that is awkward about your translation is the "作るのをはじめて” part, which I don't think is correct grammar. I think you could replace 作って in my translation with 作りはじめて, but I don't think it's required.

Commonly the "-te" form is also used to show how much time has elapsed since doing something, for example:

```
この会社に入社して１年ぐらい経ちます。　
It's been about a year since I joined this company.
```

Edit: I remembered one other pattern for the original sentence in question:

```
この料理を作るのは、これで３・４回目になるだろうな。
```

I think this is a little more literally close to the sentence.